# Mimicking PHP openssl_encrypt() and openssl_decrypt() call in Perl

Tags: php, perl, libgcrypt

I am trying to write some Perl code to decode *Triple DES* (3DES) keys generated by a PHP program. I've looked for an example of using [`Crypt::GCrypt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::GCrypt) decoding in Perl but can't find one.

I need a Perl equivalent to PHP's `openssl_decode()`, but even an encrypt/decrypt of a string does not match.

This is my test code. All values are samples for testing.

```
use strict;

{
    # match PHP's openssl_encrypt($plain_text, 'des3', $pw, 0, $iv );
    #             openssl_decrypt($cipher_text,'des3', $pw, 0, $iv );
    #   $ee = Exxx->new( %args );
    #   $cipher_text = $ee->encode( $plain_text );
    #   $plain_text  = $ee->decode( $cipher_text );

    package Exxx;

    use Crypt::GCrypt;
    use HTML::Entities;
    use MIME::Base64;

    my $ex_           = 0;
    my $exxx_method   = $ex_ ++;
    my $exxx_password = $ex_ ++;
    my $exxx_iv       = $ex_ ++;
    my $exxx_cipher   = $ex_ ++;

    sub new {
        my ( $class, $method, $passwd, $iv ) = @_;

        my $type = ref($class) ? ref($class) : __PACKAGE__;

        my $this = [];

        $this->[$exxx_method] = $method ? $method : '3des';
        $this->[$exxx_method] = '3des'    # map any PHP name to a Perl name
                if $this->[$exxx_method] eq 'des3';

        $this->[$exxx_password] = pack(
            'H*',
            $passwd ? $passwd
            : '0123456789ABCDEF' .      # key 1
              'FEDCBA9876543210' .      # key 2
              '3243F6A8885A308D' );     # key 3

        $this->[$exxx_iv] = pack(
            'H*',
            $iv ? $iv
            : '2b7e151628aed2a6' );

        bless $this, $type;

        return $this;
    }


    sub _cipher {
        my ( $this, $encrypting_decrypting ) = @_;

        my $cipher = Crypt::GCrypt->new(
            type      => 'cipher',
            algorithm => $this->[$exxx_method],
            mode      => 'cbc',
            padding   => 'standard',
        );

        $cipher->start($encrypting_decrypting);

        $cipher->setiv( $this->[$exxx_iv] );

        return $cipher;
    }


    sub encrypt {
        my ( $this, $plain_text ) = @_;

        my $cipher = $this->_cipher("encrypting");
        $cipher->encrypt($plain_text);

        my $encrypted = $cipher->finish();

        return encode_base64( $encrypted, "" );
    }


    sub encrypt_html {
        my ( $this, $plain_html ) = @_;
        return $this->encrypt( decode_entities($plain_html) );
    }


    sub decrypt {
        my ( $this, $crypt_text ) = @_;

        my $cipher     = $this->_cipher("decrypting");
        my $plain_text = $cipher->decrypt( decode_base64($crypt_text) );
        my $f          = $cipher->finish();

        return $plain_text;
    }
}

############################

my $exit          = 0;
my $plain         = 'Hello, world';                #clear text for both PHP and PERL
my $encrypted_php = 'c0WJDTwtcBsj1vTfTi7jwA==';    #crypted from PHP program

my $exxx = Exxx->new('des3');

my $encrypted = $exxx->encrypt($plain);

if ( $encrypted eq $encrypted_php ) {
    print "PASS encrypt:  (perl)$encrypted eq (php)$encrypted_php\n";
}
else {                                             #trouble.... does not match PHP
    print STDERR "ERROR encrypt: (perl)$encrypted ne (php)$encrypted_php\n";
    $exit = 1;
}

my $decrypted = $exxx->decrypt($encrypted);

if ( $plain eq $decrypted ) {                      #trouble.... does not match PHP
    print "PASS decrypt:  (perl)$plain == (perl)$decrypted\n";
    $exit = 1;
}

{                                                  #trouble.... does not match PHP
    print STDERR "ERROR decrypt: (perl)$plain ne (perl)$decrypted\n";
    $exit = 1;
}

exit $exit;
```

Comment: The final test value is Y2IA5Q74o2Y/7QjVY9Qk7T5P/pK4SZy/eR2kufFYY5iYET3RbH4zx7UziSzR/yDqYw2jE2pZogVXpdtaWL85nbM1pFMyf+RtFCWJlYWMuhQ=

Comment: If you have any choice do not use 3DES, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). Of course you have no need for security 3DES is fine.

Comment: @Gilbert: Wow. I've never had to work so hard to make someone's Perl code legible. ***Please*** read the help on using markdown (there's a link, a question mark in an orange circle, at the top-right of every post open for edit) and ***never*** use HTML markup if you can help it

Comment: I've tried to work through your code, but I'm struggling to help. I can't understand how you've learned to write Perl like that as, although using `package` within a block and basing an object on an array reference are perfectly valid, they are unfamiliar to most experienced Perl programmers. I suggest that you write your package `Exxx` in a separate file called `Exxx.pm`, and then `use Exxx` from your main code. That will help to isolate any errors, and is one of the major advantages of object-oriented programming

Comment: This `my $type = ref($class) ? ref($class) : __PACKAGE__` is horrible. It tries to support the misconception that you should be able to call the constructor on any instance of a class, and also ignores anything else that is passed as the first parameter unless it is a reference. That will break inheritance, and an illegal call like `Exxx::new({})` will result in a `HASH` object, which will break because there is no such package. This should be just `$type = $class` and perhaps `ref $type and die`

Comment: @Borodin FYI: this is throw-away test code in a single file and is to be replaced by better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the excellent [`Crypt::Cipher`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Cipher) library suite. It covers a huge number of ciphers, it is independent of any other module, and I have compiled it successfully using Visual C as well as gcc and g++ without any issues

You will need to specify `DES_EDE` (same as *Triple DES* and *3DES*) when you create a new `Crypt::Cipher` object, and the rest should be obvious

```
Crypt::Cipher->new('DES_EDE', $key);
```